# How many copies of code is bundled in the final bundle.js?

Tags: webpack

I am trying to find out how many copy of jquery is included, if I use

```
var jquery = require('jquery');
```

at the beginning of many js files packed by Webpack.

I think it should be only one. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Try bundling two files that just require jQuery and inspect the resulting bundle. It will be included once.